# Is the Australia Post CEO the highest paid postal executive on the planet?

Tags: australia, mail

There has been a lot of noise recently about how much the Australia post CEO (Ahmed Fahour) earns. One of the statements I came across was in this image that states he is the highest paid postal executive on the planet.

[image: Ahmed Fahour - Australia Post CEO - The highest paid postal executive on the planet making a whopping 5.6 million a year. Share if you think this is a disgrace.]

(This photo was found [on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/pg/IGrewUpInAustralia/photos/?ref=page_internal).)

Is this true? If not which ones earn more?

Comment: FYI: it is AUD 5.6 Million = USD 4.28 Million on todays' exchange rate

Comment: I'm more interested in the other implied question here - that there is a higher paid Postal Executive off the planet...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, he ist not the best paid Post CEO.

Frank Appel the CEO of Deutsche Post AG (German Post) has a salary of 5.2 million Euro, which when considering the current exchange rate fluctuations within the last year is somewhere between AUD 7.2 and 8.3 million.

Source: [Berliner Zeitung](http://www.berliner-zeitung.de/wirtschaft/--10809966)

Comment: How much is Ahmed Fahour paid?